# Setup Feign client and Soap WS

Tags: soap, netflix-zuul, netflix-feign

Is it possible to set up communication between Feign and soap web service ?

Any feedback is appreciated, and if you think I should take another route, please say so!

Comment: Why not? Tests used in the offical repo with SAX decoder: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/sax/src/test/java/feign/sax/SAXDecoderTest.java